# UPDATE functionality on Java Web not populating textbox when going to Update page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I have a home page who redirects to an update page when the user clicks to update an item.
I am trying to pass the ID value to the update page based on the item the user clicked, however I am unable to populate the textboxes.
Could you please assist me? I wonder where my logic is failing.

Update SQL:

```
public static void insertProduct(Product product)
{ 
    Connection connection = Database.getConnection();

    String sql = "INSERT INTO product (name, type, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    try { 
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        statement.setString(1, product.getName());
        statement.setString(2, product.getType());
        statement.setDouble(3, product.getPrice());

        statement.execute();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Controller:

```
private ProductService productService = new ProductService();

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
//  request.setAttribute("products", productService.getProducts());
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    double price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price"));
```

//      Product newProduct = new Product(name, price);

```
    request.setAttribute("products", productService.getProducts());
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp").forward(request, response); 
}
```

HTML Home page:

```
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Type</th>               
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${product.name}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${product.priceAsCurrency}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${product.type}" /></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/updateItem?id=<c:out value='${product.id}' />">Edit</a>
                    <a href="/delete?id=<c:out value='${product.id}' />">Delete</a>                     
                </td>
            </tr>
         <input id="productId" name="productId" type="hidden" value="${product.id}">
         </c:forEach>
```

Update page:

```
 <form action="updateItem" method="post">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<c:out value='${product.id}' 
 />" />       
        <tr>
            <th>Name: </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" size="45"
                        value="${product.name}"/>"
                    />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Type: </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="type" size="45"
                        value="${product.type}"/>"
                    />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Price: </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="type" size="45"
                        value="${product.price}"/>"
                    />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
```

In order to do an update, all the fields must not be null as per database requirements, so I'd like to have them populated with the current data as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens when you click Edit link ?

Comment: @benjaminc, when I click edit, it goes to the update page, and the url is /updateItem?"ID number from the item I clicked"